# How to get Angular to toggle on a button and toggle off the other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, toggle

Really simple objective but i cannot seem to get it to work. I have 2 toggles (using ionic css) that represent 2 modes. Only 1 mode can be on at a time, so when you toggle one on, the other should turn off (visually and in code).

I have binded the toggles with `ng-model` and an `ng-click`, but they are not working. This is what the toggles look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click='turnOnAC(true)' ng-model='ac'>
<input type="checkbox" ng-click='turnOnFan(true)' ng-model='fan'>
```

So when `turnOnAc(true)` is called, it should set `$scope.ac = true` and `$scope.fan = false`.

```
$scope.turnOnAC = function(bool){
    if(bool == true){
    $scope.fan = false;
        $scope.ac = true;
    }
};
```

It must be something silly I am forgetting, but I am blind to it! Could anyone help me out?

http://jsfiddle.net/dvtofn6L/59/

Comment: are you inject angular in you jsfiddle demo ?

Comment: I believe so, as it exists in the External Sources as ionic-angular. However, here is a version that uses regular angular: http://jsfiddle.net/dvtofn6L/61/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't inject `$scope` in your controller function. so you should inject `$scope` and the should working fine.

```
app.controller('NavController', function ($scope) {
```

and if you don't use `this` in your controller then you may no need to use `controller as`

so use

```
<div class="nav" ng-controller="NavControlle">
```

instead of

```
<div class="nav" ng-controller="NavController as nav">
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the $scope param in your Controller's function:

```
app.controller('NavController', function ($scope) {...
```